# Getting this SQL Statement right with aliases

Tags: sql, postgresql, alias

what i basically want to do is: compute the difference of to attributes and then get the row with the biggest difference.

So, here is what i tried:

```
SELECT caller_aor, (end_time - start_time) as duration
    FROM cdrs
    GROUP BY caller_aor
    HAVING duration = (SELECT MAX(end_time - start_time) FROM cdrs);
```

duration in the HAVING clause gives an error but i cant figure out what i have to do there.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` (they are only used when *aggregating* columns).

You want a simple `WHERE`:

```
SELECT caller_aor, (end_time - start_time) as duration
FROM cdrs
WHERE (end_time - start_time) = (SELECT MAX(end_time - start_time) FROM cdrs);
```

Comment: @void: be ready for multiple results if multiple records have the same duration.

Answer (score 2):

try this query

```
SELECT top 1 caller_aor, Max(end_time - start_time) as duration
FROM cdrs
GROUP BY caller_aor
Order by duration
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of looking at this is to use a `limit`.

```
SELECT caller_aor, (end_time-start_time) AS duration
FROM cdrs
ORDER BY duration DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hi,
thank you for your answer.
This was not an easy one. With the following statement I got close, but the duration field is still empty. 
     SELECT caller_aor, max(end_time - start_time) as duration 
         FROM cdrs 
         GROUP BY caller_aor 
         ORDER BY duration DESC 
         LIMIT 1;